# How to copy my private repo to a new public repo and retain branches and commits?

Tags: git

I have a private repo on Github that I used for a small take-home project for an interview with a company. There were 2 engineers who were watching my repo but I didn't finish the project. I want to keep working on it and add more features / scale it up in a separate public repo.

I know I cannot fork my current private repo, but I would like to copy it to a new one and maintain the branches and commits I made. I also want to remove any ties between the old and new repo so that any commits I make to the new repo will not be reflected in the old repo.

Does anyone know what git commands I should use?

I was looking into [Duplicating a Repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository) but I wasn't sure if doing a bare clone for the repo will separate the 2 repos so that any new commits will be only made to the new repo.

Comment: The instructions on the GitHub pages are correct. GitHub only associates one clone with another when you use their "fork" operation: a fork is a GItHub-side clone with added features, while regular clone-and-push is a client-side clone and push without the added features. It's the added features that make something a "GItHub fork".

Answer (score 4):

Using the git push --mirror method:

1. clone the old private repo
   `git clone`
2. [create a new public repo on github](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/create-a-repo)
3. Create a new remote for the public repository on your local machine, like this:

   `git remote add public https://github.com/benevolentBanana135/new-public-repo.git`
4. Push all branches and commits from your private repository to the public repository (that's where the magic happens):

   `git push --mirror public`

comment:

> git push --mirror pushes all branches, commits, tags, and commit
> history from the local repository to the remote repository, while git
> push --all pushes all unpushed branches from the local repository to
> the remote repository, but does not include tags or commit history.

Comment: For copying from GitHub or others, you generally want a `git clone --bare` rather than a `git clone --mirror` to avoid getting annoying diagnostics about pull references and the like, but generally this is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to

```
git clone
```

your old repo. Now let's download all branches:

```
git pull --all
```

Now, let's add a new remote, like

```
git remote add newremote git@git.assembla.com:portfolio/space.space_name.git
```

See more here: https://articles.assembla.com/en/articles/1136998-how-to-add-a-new-remote-to-your-git-repo

Now, let's push all

```
git push --all newrepo
```

Comment: Don't use `--all` with `git pull`. It doesn't do what you think it does. (It's fine with `git push`, where it does just what you think it does.)